# Tutorial for Google autocomplete places api for swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, swift

I would like to have an autocomplete textfield that autocompletes locations for me like the one for android:

https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

Does anyone know where I can find a tutorial for this or an example?

Thanks!

Comment: The [first link](https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField) from the search of "iOS autocomplete" seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @A-Live That library is written in Objective-C.  The question asks for a Swift example.

Answer (score 9):

### Steps :

1. Add the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) CocoaPods in your swift project.
2. Find your Google place API key on Google APIs Console.
3. Add following code

### ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let gpaViewController = GooglePlacesAutocomplete(
      apiKey: "YOUR GOOGLE PLACE API KEY",
      placeType: .Address
    )

    gpaViewController.placeDelegate = self

    presentViewController(gpaViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}

extension ViewController: GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate {
  func placeSelected(place: Place) {
    println(place.description)
  }

  func placeViewClosed() {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

### GooglePlacesAutocomplete.swift

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

enum PlaceType: Printable {
  case All
  case Geocode
  case Address
  case Establishment
  case Regions
  case Cities

  var description : String {
    switch self {
    case .All: return ""
    case .Geocode: return "geocode"
    case .Address: return "address"
    case .Establishment: return "establishment"
    case .Regions: return "regions"
    case .Cities: return "cities"
    }
  }
}

struct Place {
  let id: String
  let description: String
}

protocol GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate {
  func placeSelected(place: Place)
  func placeViewClosed()
}

// MARK: - GooglePlacesAutocomplete
class GooglePlacesAutocomplete: UINavigationController {
  var gpaViewController: GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer?

  var placeDelegate: GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate? {
    get { return gpaViewController?.delegate }
    set { gpaViewController?.delegate = newValue }
  }

  convenience init(apiKey: String, placeType: PlaceType = .All) {
    let gpaViewController = GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer(
      apiKey: apiKey,
      placeType: placeType
    )

    self.init(rootViewController: gpaViewController)
    self.gpaViewController = gpaViewController

    let closeButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, target: self, action: "close")

    gpaViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton
    gpaViewController.navigationItem.title = "Enter Address"
  }

  func close() {
    placeDelegate?.placeViewClosed()
  }
}

// MARK: - GooglePlaceSearchDisplayController
class GooglePlaceSearchDisplayController: UISearchDisplayController {
  override func setActive(visible: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if active == visible { return }

    searchContentsController.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    super.setActive(visible, animated: animated)

    searchContentsController.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

    if visible {
      searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
      searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
  }
}

// MARK: - GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer
class GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer: UIViewController {
  var delegate: GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate?
  var apiKey: String?
  var places = [Place]()
  var placeType: PlaceType = .All

  convenience init(apiKey: String, placeType: PlaceType = .All) {
    self.init(nibName: "GooglePlacesAutocomplete", bundle: nil)
    self.apiKey = apiKey
    self.placeType = placeType
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tv: UITableView? = searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView
    tv?.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
  }
}

// MARK: - GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer (UITableViewDataSource / UITableViewDelegate)
extension GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return places.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Get the corresponding candy from our candies array
    let place = self.places[indexPath.row]

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = place.description
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    return cell
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    delegate?.placeSelected(self.places[indexPath.row])
  }
}

// MARK: - GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer (UISearchDisplayDelegate)
extension GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer: UISearchDisplayDelegate {
  func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    getPlaces(searchString)
    return false
  }

  private func getPlaces(searchString: String) {
    Alamofire.request(.GET,
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json",
      parameters: [
        "input": searchString,
        "type": "(\(placeType.description))",
        "key": apiKey ?? ""
      ]).responseJSON { request, response, json, error in
        if let response = json as? NSDictionary {
          if let predictions = response["predictions"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
            self.places = predictions.map { (prediction: AnyObject) -> Place in
              return Place(
                id: prediction["id"] as String,
                description: prediction["description"] as String
              )
            }
          }
        }

        self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView?.reloadData()
    }
  }
}
```

### GooglePlacesAutocomplete.xib

[image: GooglePlacesAutocomplete.xib]

Hope this will help others.

Comment: I need this for objective c, do you have any ref??

Comment: Actually, i had use this in past but some of address this is not returning valid address or returning nil.

Comment: Really Nice tutorial

Comment: UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 10

Comment: What's Printable

Comment: Will this one work with address only ? or places + address ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's full updated code for Google Autocomplete place API.
Xcode 10.0 & Swift 4.2

Follow this link as to Get [Google API KEY](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start).

After Getting the API KEY
Install Cocoa Pods:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'YOUR_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME_HERE' do
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

Appdelegate File:

```
    import UIKit
    import GooglePlaces

    let GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyCuZkL7bh_hIDggnJob-b0cDueWlvRgpck"

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?


        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(GOOGLE_API_KEY)

            return true
        }

        func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
            // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
        }

        func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
            // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        }

        func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
        }

        func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        }

        func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
            // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        }


    }
```

ViewController File:

```
    import UIKit
    import GooglePlaces


    class ViewController: UIViewController ,CLLocationManagerDelegate{

        var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient!

        // Add a pair of UILabels in Interface Builder, and connect the outlets to these variables.
        @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()



        var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?
        var searchController: UISearchController?
        var resultView: UITextView?


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            locationManager.delegate = self
            if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined
            {
                locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            }
            placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()

     //       self.addToNavbar()
    //        self.addToSubview()
            self.addToPopover()

        }

        func addToNavbar(){

            resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
            resultsViewController?.delegate = self

            searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
            searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

            // Put the search bar in the navigation bar.
            searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            navigationItem.titleView = searchController?.searchBar

            // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
            // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
            definesPresentationContext = true

            // Prevent the navigation bar from being hidden when searching.
            searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        }

        func addToSubview(){
            resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
            resultsViewController?.delegate = self

            searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
            searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

            let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 65.0, width: 350.0, height: 45.0))

            subView.addSubview((searchController?.searchBar)!)
            view.addSubview(subView)
            searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

            // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
            // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
            definesPresentationContext = true
        }

        func addToPopover(){

            resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()
            resultsViewController?.delegate = self

            searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
            searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

            // Add the search bar to the right of the nav bar,
            // use a popover to display the results.
            // Set an explicit size as we don't want to use the entire nav bar.
            searchController?.searchBar.frame = (CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250.0, height: 44.0))
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: (searchController?.searchBar)!)

            // When UISearchController presents the results view, present it in
            // this view controller, not one further up the chain.
            definesPresentationContext = true

            // Keep the navigation bar visible.
            searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
            searchController?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        }



        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
        {
            print(status)
        }







        // Add a UIButton in Interface Builder, and connect the action to this function.
        @IBAction func getCurrentPlace(_ sender: UIButton) {

            placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

                self.nameLabel.text = "No current place"
                self.addressLabel.text = ""

                if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
                    print("placeLikelihoodList -- \(placeLikelihoodList)")
                    let place = placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
                    if let place = place {
                        self.nameLabel.text = place.name
                        self.addressLabel.text = place.formattedAddress?.components(separatedBy: ", ")
                            .joined(separator: "\n")

                        print(place.name)
                        print(place.coordinate)
                        print(place.placeID)
                        print(place.phoneNumber)
                        print(place.formattedAddress ?? "")

                    }
                }
            })
        }


    }




    //MARK: Extentions

    // Handle the user's selection.
    extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
        func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                               didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
            searchController?.isActive = false
            // Do something with the selected place.
            print("Place name: \(place.name)")
            print("Place address: \(String(describing: place.formattedAddress))")
            print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
        }

        func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                               didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
            // TODO: handle the error.
            print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
        }

        // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
        func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        }

        func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

## Lightweight Solution!

Instead of using Google framework and Third party library to make simple requests I created a simple library where you can Make a number of Google api requests like `Google Autocomplete`, `Google ReverseGeo` , `Place Information` and `Path` api for getting path between two location.

To use the library all you have to do is

### step-1 Import `GoogleApiHelper` into your project.

### step-2 Initialise  `GoogleApiHelper`

```
GoogleApi.shared.initialiseWithKey("API_KEY")
```

### step-3 Call the methods

```
var input = GInput()
input.keyword = "San francisco"
GoogleApi.shared.callApi(input: input) { (response) in
    if let results = response.data as? [GApiResponse.Autocomplete], response.isValidFor(.autocomplete) {
        //Enjoy the Autocomplete Api
    } else { print(response.error ?? "ERROR") }
}
```

[You can find the library here](https://github.com/tryWabbit/Google-Api-Helper)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using Alamofire get the autocomplete Google places result from data, you can show it in table view cell

**plist configuration**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

**Code**

```
import UIKit
    import Alamofire
    class GooglePlacesViewController: UIViewController,UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var srchLocation: UISearchBar!

        @IBOutlet weak var tblLoction: UITableView!
        var arrPlaces = NSMutableArray(capacity: 100)
        let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
        let currentLat = 51.5033640
        let currentLong = -0.1276250
        var LocationDataDelegate : LocationData! = nil
        var tblLocation : UITableView!
        var lblNodata = UILabel()

        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
             super.viewDidLoad()
            lblNodata.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 80, width: 
            self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height-60)
            lblNodata.text = "Please enter text to get your location"
            self.view.addSubview(lblNodata)
            srchLocation.placeholder = "Ente your location details"
            lblNodata.textAlignment = .center     
            srchLocation.delegate = self
        }
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            self.beginSearching(searchText: searchText)
        }

        func beginSearching(searchText:String) {
            if searchText.characters.count == 0 {
                self.arrPlaces.removeAllObjects()
                tblLoction.isHidden = true
                lblNodata.isHidden = false
                return
            }

            operationQueue.addOperation { () -> Void in
                self.forwardGeoCoding(searchText: searchText)
            }
        }

        //MARK: - Search place from Google -
        func forwardGeoCoding(searchText:String) {
            googlePlacesResult(input: searchText) { (result) -> Void in
                let searchResult:NSDictionary = ["keyword":searchText,"results":result]
                if result.count > 0
                {
                    let features = searchResult.value(forKey: "results") as! NSArray
                    self.arrPlaces = NSMutableArray(capacity: 100)
                    print(features.count)
                    for jk in 0...features.count-1
                    {
                        let dict = features.object(at: jk) as! NSDictionary
                        self.arrPlaces.add(dict)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        if self.arrPlaces.count != 0
                        {
                            self.tblLoction.isHidden = false
                            self.lblNodata.isHidden = true
                            self.tblLoction.reloadData()
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            self.tblLoction.isHidden = true
                            self.lblNodata.isHidden = false
                            self.tblLoction.reloadData()
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        //MARK: - Google place API request -
        func googlePlacesResult(input: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: NSArray) -> Void) {
            let searchWordProtection = input.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "");        if searchWordProtection.characters.count != 0 {
                let urlString = NSString(format: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&types=establishment|geocode&location=%@,%@&radius=500&language=en&key= your key",input,"\(currentLocationLatitude)","\(currentLocationLongtitude)")
                print(urlString)
                let url = NSURL(string: urlString.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
                print(url!)
                let defaultConfigObject = URLSessionConfiguration.default
                let delegateFreeSession = URLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
                let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
                let task =  delegateFreeSession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler:
                {
                    (data, response, error) -> Void in
                    if let data = data
                    {
                        do {
                            let jSONresult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                            let results:NSArray = jSONresult["predictions"] as! NSArray
                            let status = jSONresult["status"] as! String
                            if status == "NOT_FOUND" || status == "REQUEST_DENIED"
                            {
                                let userInfo:NSDictionary = ["error": jSONresult["status"]!]
                                let newError = NSError(domain: "API Error", code: 666, userInfo: userInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject])
                                let arr:NSArray = [newError]
                                completion(arr)
                                return
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                completion(results)
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            print("json error: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                    else if let error = error
                    {                                                              
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
                task.resume()
            }
        }
        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return arrPlaces.count
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            let tblCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "locationCell")
            let dict = arrPlaces.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
            tblCell?.textLabel?.text = dict.value(forKey: "description") as? String
            tblCell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            tblCell?.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
            return tblCell!
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        {
            if LocationDataDelegate != nil
            {
                let dict = arrPlaces.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
                print(dict.value(forKey: "terms") as! NSArray)
                let ArrSelected = dict.value(forKey: "terms") as! NSArray
                LocationDataDelegate.didSelectLocationData(LocationData: ArrSelected)
            }
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class AddNewAddressVC: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate{
         
func autocompleteClicked() {
            let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
            autocompleteController.delegate = self
    
            // Specify the place data types to return.
            let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) |
              UInt(GMSPlaceField.placeID.rawValue))!
            autocompleteController.placeFields = fields
    
            // Specify a filter.
            let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
            filter.type = .address
            autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
    
            // Display the autocomplete view controller.
            present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
          }
    
    @IBAction func action_selectGooglePlaces(_ sender: UIButton) {
            autocompleteClicked()
        }
    
}
    
    
    extension AddNewAddressVC: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {
    
      // Handle the user's selection.
      func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
        print("Place name: \(place.name)")
        print("Place ID: \(place.placeID)")
        print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
    
      func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
        // TODO: handle the error.
        print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
      }
    
      // User canceled the operation.
      func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
    
      // Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
      func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
      }
    
      func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
      }
    
    }
```