# iOS: Google Places Pod - reached usage limit error after upgrade pod version to 3.1.0

Tags: ios, swift, google-places

Google recomments to upgrade the iOS Google Places Pod from `2.7.0` to `3.1.0`.

> Version 2.7.0 of the Places SDK for iOS is deprecated as of January 29, 2019, and will be turned off on July 29, 2019

I upgraded my pod and now I run into the following issue.

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation failed due to exceeding the quota usage limit. See the usage limits guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/usage) for information on usage limits and how to request a higher limit.

When I downgrade the version again to `2.7.0` everything works fine with the same API Key.

My limits are 1000 requests per day and I didn't reach them yet.

[image]

It is in german but you can see I had 142 requests in the last 7 days.

A confusing thing is that when I use

```
placesClient?.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in ...
```

I got my current place. When I want to use find autocomplete I'm restricted.

```
placesClient?.findAutocompletePredictions(fromQuery: searchText, bounds: nil, boundsMode: .bias, filter: nil, sessionToken: token, callback: { (gmsAutocompletePrediction, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription) // limit reached error
        }
    })
```

Do I overlook something? What else can I do? I can not imagine that the error lies with the pod.

Similar questions which not helped:

- [Google Places AutoComplete on iOS - Can't Load Search Results - Try Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165012/google-places-autocomplete-on-ios-cant-load-search-results-try-again/44165485#44165485)

Comment: Google has changed its pricing. Check a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644324/gmsautocompleteviewcontroller-showing-only-5-results) I asked few days back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GMSAutocompleteViewController showing only 5 results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55644324/gmsautocompleteviewcontroller-showing-only-5-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same problem. Was trying to implement the New Places API from Google to replace the old SDK's Place Picker. After one or two successful calls per day I always started getting the following error:

> An error occurred: The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation
>   failed due to exceeding the quota usage limit. See the usage limits
>   guide (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/usage) for
>   information on usage limits and how to request a higher limit.

I had the Places API enabled in the console and also enabled billing with a valid credit card. Was still getting this error.

The solution was to enable Maps SDK for iOS from the Google Cloud Platform. After that I had no limits to the requests and was getting results every time. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing just happened to me. You need to [increase your quota limit](https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/quota-pricing#view-your-quota)

The google's developer console is HORRIBLY laid out. Going to that link you might or might not find anything to actually increase the quota. On the `Credentials` you'll see a blue button that says "increase quota" or "request increase", it's something along the lines of this

[image]

Assuming you already setup billing, once you increase the quota you won't have any more problems.